# What is meant by a type that denotes an implicit conversion

Tags: scala, implicit

The [scala language specification, section 7.2](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html) is about implicit scope: 
It explains that implicit scope are the modules associated in some way with the parts of type `T`. What the parts of T are is listed below. One of those points is

> if `T` denotes an implicit conversion to a type with a method with
>   argument types `T1,…,Tn` and result type `U`, the union of the parts of
>   T1,…,Tn and U;

I can't make head or tails from this. I don't understand how a type T can denote an implicit conversion.

What is meant by this part of the specification of implicit scope?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is referring to the following situation

```
case class Foo(v: Int)
object Foo {
  implicit def stringToFoo(s: String) = Foo(42)
}

def f[A](v: A)(implicit ev: A => Foo) = ev(v)

f("woohoo")
```

where the implicit conversion `type T = A => Foo`, and `Foo` is the **part** associated with type parameter `A`, therefore `object Foo` becomes part of the implicit scope and `stringToFoo` implicit conversion is resolved without needing an import.

Comment: I don't think this rule is used here; `A => Foo` is `Function1[A, Foo]` so its parts include `Foo` by the rule for parametrized types. (I added my own answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples:

```
trait A
object A {
  implicit def f(a: A): B = null
}

trait B

val b: B = new A {} // compiles
```

or

```
trait A

trait B
object B {
  implicit def f(a: A): B = null
}

val b: B = new A {} // compiles
```

Let `T` denote an implicit conversion to a type, from `A` to `B` (`val b: B = new A {}`), it denotes the conversion with a method with argument types `T1,…,Tn = A` and result type `U = B`. So the *parts* of T are the union of the parts of `A` and parts of `B`. So an implicit can be defined as a member of the companion object of a base class of the parts of `T` (i.e. `A` or `B`).